# hover effect that make some object to change or move, using (maybe) processing.js?

Tags: object, menu, hover, effect, processing.js

I spent whole night to figure it out how does hover effect on this site http://goo.gl/WXlGT work. But i still cant get it. At first i thought that its made in flash, than i thought its html5 but finally i found out its using ***processing.js*** (i can be wrong). I checked their sites but i have no idea how to do it.

All what i want to know is how to make hover effect of one object (for example menu) that will make some other object (for example logo) to change or move. Perfect example of what im looking for is here: http://goo.gl/I777F .

Any help or hints to some manual on web would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a general object oriented programming question, with a general object oriented answer. In generic Processing code:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> things;

...

void somePlacementFunction() {
  ...
  things.add(new Drawable(<some parameters>));
  ... 
}

...

void draw() {
  for(Drawable things: things) {
    thing.draw();
  }
}

...

void mouseMoved() {
  for(Drawable thing: things) {
    if(thing.over(mouseX, mouseY)) {
      Drawable differentThing = getOtherThing(...);
      differentThing.changeSomePropertyThatAffectsHowItGetsDrawn();
    }
  }
}
```

In this specific case, the Processing code is http://labfiftyfive.com/res/mathsbaby2.pde and the on-page JS triggers it as http://labfiftyfive.com/js/main.js line 162 and on.